Meaning of $\langle M,\,M^{-1}\rangle$
For an $n\times n$ complex matrix $M$, is there a name for the expression $\langle M,\,M^{-1}\rangle$, where the inner product is the Frobenius one, $\langle A,\,B\rangle=\text{tr}(A^*B)$? Is there a characterization of it's level sets? I would appreciate references to anywhere this quantity has appeared in the literature.
